# How to create activities for the items that were added dynamically in the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, shopping-cart

I'm creating a simple Shopping list Android app.

In this the users create different lists and add dynamic list items to the list.

how should I create different activities for the each custom list item?

I have Googled and searched in the stackoverflow website too, but I didn't find the actual solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a common activity defined to do whatever action you want to do when an item is clicked. This activity should be modeled to act on a specific format of an object.

Model this object in your previous activity using the item clicked on, and pass this object to your new activity using the [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and adding it as an extra.

**HOW?** you may ask.

1. Have your activity (let's say ProductDisplay Activity) do something like display the product name, and price.
2. Implement your Product class as a Parcelable, and create a new instance of it when the user clicks on one list item.
3. Populate the instance with the specifics of the product clicked on.
4. Pass this intent as an extra to ProductDisplay.
5. Receive this extra in ProductDisplay as an instance of Product.
6. Use the name and price from the Product object to display all the specifics of that product.

Some examples of using Parcelables like this can be found [here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html), and [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html).